# Like condition in Xpath expresseion

Tags: xml, xpath

Having difficulty finding the correct syntax (or I am going about this the wrong way), to use a like condition in an XPath expression.

If I use an equal operator, it works and I can move forward.

```
/*[/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id='atom3']/BOM/BO/Document_Lines/row/ItemCode = 'E1234' ]
```

What I am after is specifically trying to see if the element starts with the character 'E'.

I have tried:

```
 /*[/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id='atom3']/BOM/BO/Document_Lines/row/ItemCode = 'E*' ]
```

as well as a variation of the starts-with function but to no avail.

Hoping someone can give me a pointer or give the correct syntax.

Comment: When you say "like condition", I think you are referring to the "LIKE" operator in SQL. Not everyone here knows SQL.

Comment: I'll remember that for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`starts-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-starts-with)

```
/*[/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id='atom3']/BOM/BO/Document_Lines/row[starts-with(ItemCode,'E')]]
```

or [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-matches) with a regex pattern:

```
/*[/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id='atom3']/BOM/BO/Document_Lines/row[matches(ItemCode,'^E.*')]]
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked - thank you! I'm pretty sure I did use that but I think I used it with a wildcard(*) which skipped the flow.